# I'm getting a NameError: and I'm new to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
flag = True
principleAmount = float(input("Please enter a principal amount: "))
while(flag):
    userInput = str(input("(s)imple or (c)ompound interest? "))
    if userInput in ['s', 'S']:
        print("hello")
    elif userInput in ['c', 'C']:
        print("goodbye")
    else: 
        print("wrong!")
```

For some reason, this is the error that I'm getting:
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 's' is not defined
It's the same with c as well.
I was trying to test it with the hello, goodbye, and wrong, but unfortunately it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine except the while loop runs forever.

Comment: I believe that my Net Beans that has Python has version 2.x version of Python instead of 3.x. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine in Python 3 (aside from never exiting, because you don't change the value of `flag`).

But the error you're seeing only makes sense in Python *2*, where `input` is implemented as accepting a string and `eval`ing it. That would explain both the line number of the error (nothing on line 1 could possibly raise `NameError`, but `eval` effectively treats the code being evaluated as beginning on line 1 from scratch), and the error (`eval`ing an `input` of `s` would try to lookup a variable named `s`, it wouldn't produce a string with the value `'s'`).

**So the solution to your primary problem is either**:

1. Actually run on Python 3, not Python 2, or
2. Change all uses of `input` to `raw_input` (which is the Python 2 equivalent of Python 3's `input` function, which accepts a string without trying to `eval` it)

While you're at it, you can:

1. Remove the `str()` wrapping around the second `input`, since Py2 `raw_input`/Py3 `input` are already guaranteed to return a `str`, and wrapping in `str` is just needless thumb twiddling
2. Add `flag = False` (or `break`) to the block controlled by `elif userInput in ['c', 'C']:` so when you say `goodbye` you actually terminate the loop.

Comment: I believe that my Net Beans that has Python has version 2.x version of Python instead of 3.x. Thank you so much!